# Zend Framework: Errors are not visible/displayed

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have following form class:

```
$username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
$username->setLabel('Username:')
      ->setRequired(true)
      ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
      ->addFilter('StringTrim')
      ->setAttribs(array('class' => 'textfield'));

$submit = $this->createElement('submit', 'mySubmit');
$submit->setLabel('Login')
       ->setAttribs(array('id' => 'btnsubmit', 'class' => 'btn'));

$reset = $this->createElement('reset', 'myReset');
$reset->setLabel('Reset')
      ->setAttribs(array('id' => 'btnreset', 'class' => 'btn'));

$this->addElements(array($username, $submit, $reset));

$this->setElementDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array('Label', array('class' => 'login_label', 'placement'=> 'REPLACE')),
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag'=> 'p')),    
));

 $this->setDecorators(array(
     'FormElements',
     'Form',             
     array('Fieldset', array('legend' => 'Login Info')), 
     array(array('mydiv' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' =>'div', 'id' => 'lgrd')),
 ));
```

And following is Action Controller code:

```
$form = new Application_Form_Adminlogin();
$this->view->form = $form;
```

If I submit blank username field, then no error shows on the page. Can some one guide me what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On the post, are you doing `$form->isValid($form->getValues());`? If you are, looking at the code provided you should see errors at each invalid field

Comment: @adlawson: Are you sure about that? $form->getValues() doesn't return any values until _after_ a call to `$form->isValid($data)`, where typically `$data` is something like $`request->getPost()`. Typo, right?

Comment: No, not a typo. If $form->getValues(); returns empty, then your form hasn't been populated with the post values. You should do `$form->populate($this->getRequest()->getPost()); $form->isValid($form->getValues());`. The benefit of populating the form first is if you specify element filters, the values are filtered before validation.

Comment: @adlawson: Aaah, I see what you mean. We're crossing wires a bit, but I think we agree on the core issue: `$form->getValues()` requires that form actually has some values, typically from `$form->populate($data)`, `$form->setDefaults($data)`, or `$form->isValid($data)`. So if he uses - probably incorrectly - `$form->isValid($form->getValues())`, then it should evaluate to false and the form should have all his errors. Right?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. `isValid()` requires data through one of the three methods you mentioned. The difference, however, with setting the data in `isValid()` is that any filters assigned to elements won't be used. I will review what I said before about having to then call `$form->isValid($form->getValues());` as you should be able to call it without parameters after setting the data via `populate()` or `setDefaults()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend_Form does not automatically populate/validate itself agaist GET/POST variables.

As noted in the comments, you should do this:

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
if($form->isValid($postData)) {
  // Do what you need to do when form is valid
} else {
  // Do what you need to do when form is NOT valid
}
$this->view->form = $form;
```

This should also show errors when the form displayed after incorrect parameters were input.

Comment: Just like in my last comment on the question, you should pass `$postData` to `$form->populate();` to filter the data according to any filters added to the elements. Then you need to call `$form->isValid($form->getValues());`

Comment: isValid() automatically populates the form, there is no need for a separate call to populate()